# fastboot works, adb doesn't

Tags: adb, usb, fastboot, hardware

I picked up a second-hand Motorola Moto G (2nd gen) device. The model is technically XT1064 (Titan).

On my Windows machine, I'm sometimes able to see an error message when I power down the phone stating that the USB device was unrecognized (Device Descriptor Request Failed).

After days of trying, I've yet to have it show up in `adb`. But it works just fine if I boot into the bootloader and run `fastboot` commands!

I've tried all of the "easy" things people recommend:

- enabling USB debugging under Developer Options
- different USB cables (although since `fastboot` works fine, that implies the cable is also fine)
- different computers (tried a Mac, a Windows 10 machine, and a Windows Vista laptop)
- `adb kill-server` followed by `adb devices`
- various `adb` versions (Android SDK platform tools and Universal ADB driver)
- manually uninstalling Windows drivers
- force installing drivers (doesn't work, since the device doesn't make it past the device descriptor request so Windows won't allow drivers to be installed)
- installing the Universal ADB driver
- re-flashing the device (tried stock Marshmallow, stock KitKat, and Lineage OS)

I'm frustrated by the process because `fastboot` works just fine. That's how I've flashed the separate ROMs on there.

If this were a hardware issue with USB, why would it be that `fastboot` operates correctly but `adb` does not?

Also, if it's a hardware issue, what physical part would be the problem? It seems unlikely to be the USB port itself (again, because `fastboot` works just fine). Is there some kind of USB controller in the phone that could be the issue? Since the device is pretty useless to me unless `adb` works, I'd entertain the idea of trying to solder in a new part to fix the problem if I could!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your device is rooted, you may set up adb over network as a workaround for all USB driver problems.

- Make sure both PC and Android device are in same network
- On Android, install Terminal Emulator
- Open Terminal Emulator and type the following:

`su`
`setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555`
`stop adbd`
`start adbd`

- On a PC side, enter:

`adb connect 192.168.1.2`

(replace 192.168.1.2 with the IP address of your device)

- Proceed with adb as if it was connected over USB

Alternatively, you may create a script with GScript instead of using Terminal Emulator.
Also, you can add these lines to your Android boot scripts, in which case you don't have to do it manually every time.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I ended up doing! I didn't need to root the device -- I just installed LineageOS and it supported it right out of the box. I just use `adb connect` and everything works fine. Although this is a great *workaround*, I'm not sure it's a *solution* to the problem. But it's definitely what I did, so I upvoted you. Thanks for the great suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

***You may need to enable USB Debugging enabled***

**To enable follow these steps:**

1. Open settings
2. Open `Info`
3. Find the `Build Number` and tap on it alot until it says `You are now a developer!`
4. Exit `Info`
5. Open `Developer options`
6. Tap on `USB debugging`
7. Tap on `OK`

**Notes:**

- In 4.1.x and before skip steps 2-4
- In 2.2.x and before goto `Settings`->`Applications`->`Development`->`USB debugging`

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that to the list of things I've tried :). Doesn't work!

Comment: @aardvarkk it's OK, I would have commented asking if you had, just to make sure, but I can't comment yet so... I made an answer about it

Comment: @aardvarkk, have you tried the device's default windows drivers?

Comment: Yeah, I installed the drivers from the original manufacturer. But I think it's a deeper issue since the device doesn't even get to the point of trying to use drivers -- it fails on the Device Descriptor Request.

Comment: I'm not meaning ones you download, ones that Windows installs by itself

Comment: Oh, yeah, those definitely don't work. Windows doesn't even attempt a driver install. Doesn't even bring up a message, really, when I plug it in. I'm guessing because it's failing so early in the device identification.

Comment: @aardvarkk, Even in Vista?

Answer (score 1):

fastboot works, adb doesn't?
my ans: you can use image loader which is compatible with that device,erase all the previous data and freshly build new Meta data by including the partitioning,after success u might get expected output like flatten success(related to build of that device).then adb will work fine with usb port detection.

hopes this works!